# How to identify a research question as artificial

Tags: research-process

I recently go through an interview on the basis of my research proposal and the person evaluating me said my research questions are artificial. I want to ask which characteristics make the research question not artificial?

Comment: What does this mean? I'm having a hard time understanding your question?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable in general. An expert in the field will be able to recognize dead-ends and blind attempts in that field. It might be better (in some places) to mention an area that you would like to explore rather than anything too specific.

Comment: He was not the expert in my area but even than he said after the interview (there was panel of people with different expertise). How can I justify that the research question is an artificial one or not?

Comment: I found the clarification sufficient to answer, and have done so. I have thus also voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's hard to know without knowing all of the specifics, it seems likely to me that this criticism is similar to saying that the questions are poorly motivated.

There are an unlimited number of research questions that might be asked. Why are these the ones that are interesting?  Consider that in many cases, a specific research question may be seen as a "natural" consequence of the underlying motivation.

For example, if one was studying cancer and noticed that a particular group of people got cancer much less than expected, the "natural" research questions might include whether they have different genetics or different habits or whether this is related to other known modulators of cancer frequency, or whether other groups of people with related characteristics can be predicted to have different cancer rates.  All of these might have obvious interesting consequences for the understanding and management of cancer.

An "artificial" question, by contrast, would be any question for which no such clear narrative is available.  It will be at least partially a matter of perspective, but rather than debating whether a question is artificial, it would be good to examine whether it is really well motivated. If so, explain the motivation better.  If not, get a more interesting question.